# Could someone explain me how Laravel QueryLog behaves when many users?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I am doing a trait to log eloquent events with their raw query.

Right now in development, it works perfectly for the use cases, but I was wondering how it will behave with many users. I tested with 4 users simultaneously and did not get any problem.

Basically this is the code for the trait:

```
public static function boot()
{
  static::creating(function ($model){
      DB::enableQueryLog();
  });

  static::created(function ($model) {
     print_r($model);
     print_r(DB::getQueryLog());
  });
}
```

With many users, will it get mixed?

Comment: I'm guessing the by **"I tested with 4 users simultaneously"** you're referring to 4 simultaneous requests. The idea is that the Laravel's query log works on a per request basis. So no matter if you have 1000 simultaneous requests you still get a different log on each individual request.

Comment: Yes, you are right about 4 simultaneous requests. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone finish here,

The answer is: query_log does not depend on user but on the connection this user has with the DB. As I understood it, it works at transaction level then it would not mix with other users.

As for why it is like this, it is because Laravel and Mysql, both comply to the four ACID properties in a DBMS, specifically for this case is the Isolation one.